# How can I get Django Objects which Date has Not Passed

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project where I want to get all Event Tickets that the Event Date has not passed. That is, I have an event table with some fields amongst them is date and every Ticket is tied to an event, and I want a situation where I can display a List of Tickets that their Events has not passed the current date. For example if a Birthday Event has a date of 12/09/2022 and a Ticket has been created on this event then by today (13/09/2022) this Event should not be listed for Tickets to be generated.

I have tried to figure it out but couldn't get it working the way I explained above, may be I am missing out something.
Here is my Models code:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=False)
    event_venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_logo = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', blank=False, null=False, upload_to ='profile_images')
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event_name}"

    #Prepare the url path for the Model
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("event_detail", args=[str(self.id)])

class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PASS, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    added_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event} "

    #Prepare the url path for the Model
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ticket-detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

Here is my views code:

```
def Ticket_list(request):


    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(event__date__lte=datetime.today())
    context = {
    'tickets':tickets,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/ticket_list.html', context)
```

Your answer shall highly be appreciated. thanks

Comment: `event__date__gte=datetime.today()` does not work? This means it will only get tickets with events from the future. Since it is filtering by time GREATER THAN today, instead of filtering by the past (LTE)

Comment: @nigel239 yes I want to get events that their date is yet to come or equal to today

Comment: @nigel239 thanks. I was actually doing the opposite as you pointed out in your comment.